# pm2 creates a "source" directory and copies all my files inside, why?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, pm2

I deleted my previous question because it was not very clear, and the problem was not clearly exposed. I have an instance @aws, a repository @gitlab, and gitlab CI is setup.
I made a little app in node.js because I want to try all these new stuff.
But, when gitlab-ci runs the script, pm2 creates a "source" directory in my folder, then copied all my files in this directory, which is appearently the Current Working Directory (CWD).
That's a surprising behavior, and I'm not comfortable with it.

Anyone knows why ? Is it normal ? Why can't my files stay in ~/projet2/, as I set up ?

When I run `pm2 show projet2`, I can see the `exec cwd` is `/home/ubuntu/projet2/source` while `source` is a folder I've never created !

.git-ci.yml

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official framework image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/
image: node:alpine

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk add --update openssh )'

    # Add bash
    - apk add --update bash

    # Add git
    - apk add --update git

    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > "./pk.pem"
    - chmod 400 ./pk.pem
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -

    # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
    # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
    # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
    # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    # In order to properly check the server's host key, assuming you created the
    # SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS variable previously, uncomment the following two lines
    # instead.
    # - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    # - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
  script:
  - npm i -g pm2
  - pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production setup
  - pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production
  only:
  - master
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'projet2',
    script: '/home/ubuntu/projet2/index.js',
    cwd: '/home/ubuntu/projet2/'
  }],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: 'ubuntu',
      host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      ref: 'origin/master',
      repo: 'git@gitlab.com:xxxxxxx/projet2.git',
      key: './pk.pem',
      path: '/home/ubuntu/projet2/',
      'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 startOrRestart /home/ubuntu/projet2/ecosystem.config.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is older but in case others still end up here I wanted to say me too :) Also:

My workaround is a hack to cp -r from /source to ./ as the first command in 'post-deploy'. I was unable to find the correct solution and this worked for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: **Yes! This is normal behavior!**

It is to be expected, since you are running things with pm2 now, and pm2 knows how to handle it.

By running:

`pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js someName`

the pm2 is making an SSH to the provided host, using the provided user and key. Then, on a successful connection to the provided host, pm2 proceeds to try and do a `git pull` from the provided referenced branch inside ref, which belongs to the provided repo. The pulled data will be placed in the provided path inside 'path', **with the addition of a 'source' directory**. After a successful pull, the post-deploy will be triggered, which is in charge of doing the `npm install` and then some more stuff (depending on what you tell it to do). But nevertheless, the creation of the source folder is something that is built-in to the pm2 mechanism, and is to be expected. It shouldn't bother you too much.